# How can I say the length of the string can be maximum 8 (Regex)

Tags: regex, parsing

```
^([A-Za-z]{4,}(\d{1,2})){,8}$
```

I have this regex, I'm basically trying say that alpha characters can be minumum 4 characters then followed by 1 or 2 digits, BUT THE WHOLE THING SHOULD NOT EXCEED 8 characters

Example:

```
dona45, donas1, dona23, donalsf1 (Valid Ones)
don2, dona212,donasase, donasese1, donasease (invalid)
```

What is wrong with my regex?

Comment: Without lookaheads : `^([A-Za-z]{4,6}\d{1,2}|[A-Za-z]{7}\d)$` With lookaheads : `^(?=.{5,8}$)([A-Za-z]{4,}\d{1,2})$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookahead based regex:

```
\b(?=[a-zA-Z\d]{4,8}\b)[a-zA-Z]{4,}\d{1,2}\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pJ1aZ1/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
\b                     # word boundary
(?=[a-zA-Z\d]{4,8}\b)  # lookahead to allow between 4 to 8 alpha-numeric chars
[a-zA-Z]{4,}           # match minimum 4 alphabets
\d{1,2}                # match 1 or 2 digits
\b                     # word boundary
```

Answer (score 1):

The `{,8}` at the end of your expression is allowing the entire preceding regex to be duplicated up to 8 times. You might want to try throwing in two layers of regex - one to check for each criterion:

```
^[A-Za-z]{4,}(\d{1,2})$
```

then feed the output through

```
^.{,8}$
```

Comment: I don't believe that `{,8}` is a valid range quantifier. I'm pretty certain that will match literally the characters `{,8}`.

Comment: @Trey Depends on the regex engine. Many engines interpret the above as `{0,8}`.

Comment: @KennethK. That makes sense, but why not just explicitly use `{0,n}`? For example, it doesn't work with http://regex101.com using any regex flavor.